# Creating Range Buckets of column

Tags: sql, h2

I am having one base table named test_table on which I am doing calculation of the age and it is coming as per expectation.

Here is the query I am using for age calculation.

```
select acol,
       DATEDIFF(hour,CONVERT(DATEADD('SECOND', (epoch_time)/1000, DATE '1970-01-01'), DATE), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS age
from test_table;
```

But now I want to create different range of age column which will be displayed as a result by modifying the existing query.

Range would be :

```
1000-2000

2000-3000

3000-4000

ACOL       AGE  
MAG        1168
MAG        2168
MAG        3168
MAG        1100
MAG        2168
PNB        1672
MUM        1600
MUM        2696
MUM        3696
MUM        1696
```

Result after successful query has to look like below table.

```
ACOL 1000-2000  2000-3000 3000-4000
MAG      2          2          1
PNB      1          0          0
MUM      2          1          1
```

I know that we can do this using select case but not able to build the working query.
can anyone help me in this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT t.ACOL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.AGE >= 1000 AND t.AGE < 2000 THEN t.AGE ELSE 0 END) AS `1000-2000`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.AGE < 3000 THEN t.AGE ELSE 0 END) AS `2000-3000`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.AGE < 3000 AND t.AGE < 4000 THEN t.AGE ELSE 0 END) AS `3000-4000`
FROM
(
    SELECT ACOL,
           DATEDIFF(HOUR, CONVERT(DATEADD(SECOND, (epoch_time)/1000, DATE '1970-01-01'), DATE), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS AGE
    FROM test_table
) t
GROUP BY t.ACOL
```

Comment: Can we add DATEDIFF(hour,CONVERT(DATEADD('SECOND', (epoch_time)/1000, DATE '1970-01-01'), DATE), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS age from test_table;  instead of typing age

Comment: Because I am doing operation on test_table and creating age as a result...

Comment: @Apurv I wrapped your initial query which calculates the age as a subquery, and then used the same logic as my original answer.

Comment: Yeah, I did same and also changed sum to count function with null as a result when case is false. And it's working as expected. YOU can check query in my answer...Thanks a lot cheers

Comment: @Apurv: If this answer helped you, why aren't you upvoting at the very least?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ACOL,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN AGE >= 1000 AND AGE < 2000 THEN AGE ELSE NULL END) AS `1000-2000`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN AGE >= 2000 AGE < 3000  THEN AGE ELSE NULL END) AS `2000-3000`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN AGE >= 3000 AND AGE < 4000 THEN AGE ELSE NULL END) AS `3000-4000`
FROM (select ACOL,DATEDIFF(hour,CONVERT(DATEADD('SECOND', (epoch_time)/1000, DATE '1970-01-01'), DATE), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS AGE FROM test_table )
GROUP BY ACOL
```

Modified the from clause...
Working ... 
:)